# boost build: missing rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, b2

I am trying to build boost and am getting an error:

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_77_0> .\b2
boostcpp.jam: No such file or directory
Jamroot:153: in modules.load
ERROR: rule "boostcpp.set-version" unknown in module "Jamfile<C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_77_0>".
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:372: in load-jamfile
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:142: in project.find
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:618: in load
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

The directory `boost_1_77_0` has two jam-files:  `project-config.jam` and `boost-build.jam`.  Which of these files is `b2` looking for the rule in?  And how do I define the missing rule?  The `b2` documentation is no help.